# Communicating between two MediaController with same MediaSession

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer, android-mediasession

Let's say I have two activities Activity A and Activity B.

I have created a `MediaBrowser` object in Activity A and in the `onConnected` callback of it I have created the `MediaController` with mediaSession.

Now I want the another `MediaController` in Activity B so that if any changes occur in mediaSession, then it will be reflected in both the activites and can be catched up by both the `mediaControllers` and could upate their respective UI's.

How Can I do this.

Comment: You can make it static and access directly in any activity . I did this in an app  and it worked like charm.

Comment: Memory leakage issue comes when we declare static. Is there any other way round.

Comment: yes but it can be prevented if you handle the code properly. for example clearing the instances before closing activity and stopping player etc.

Comment: Another solution is to do it in fragments by taking controller in the parent activity.

Comment: Yeah but i want it in different activities only not in fragment